# Get javascript result in html from control event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC, so I don't really know what is the approach for this:
I want that on the hover of one label, other labels get generated based on the collection returned by a mouseover javascript, something like this:

```
<script....
  function getSongs(genreId)
     { return collection of Song objects }

</script>
<div>
   @foreach(Genre genre in Genres)
     {
       <div> <label onmouseover= "here send @genre.Id to the function that will handle this and that will return a collection of Song objects"> @genre.Text </label> </div>
     }
</div>
<div>
   @foreach(Song song in the collection returned by the js function)
    {  <div> <label> @song.Title </label> </div> }
</div>
```

I wrote this example here, didn't paste it from vs, so sorry  if there are some syntax mistakes.
What would be the correct approach for this and if this is the right approach then how should be this accomplished? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize the Song objects from Genres as JSON and store it in a js variable. You can do this with Razor/C# using the JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(songsList). Depending on how your data is structured, you either need to create something like a dictionary in javascript that has the 'genreId' as the key and the 'listOfSongs' for its value, or - If you have the GenreId in the Song object - , you don't need this as the serialized data will contain the GenreId to fetch the songs for.

When iterating through the Genres collection, you could set to the inner label a 'data-genreId' attribute that should have genre.Id value.

Then, on mouseover callback you can grab the element that was hovered and read the 'data-genreId' attribute's value - this should give you the genreId. Having this Id, you'll need to grab the songs out of the collection mentioned in the beginning using js. Once you have the list of songs, you can create html elements that hold song information (title like you mentioned) and inject them in the page in a div placeholder for example.

Also, I don't think you'll need the last foreach as it is in the example you provided as this will be filled dynamically when hovering the label with the approach I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup little bit. Here i am changing the label tag to an anchor tag using the [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) html helper method.

```
<div>
 @foreach(Genre genre in Genres)
 {
    <div>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,"Songs","Genre",
                          new { id=genre.ID},new { @class="lnkGenre"})</div>
 }
</div>
<div id="songList"></div>
```

This will generate a list of anchor tags like this.

```
<a href="/Genre/Songs/24" class="lnkGenre">Pop</a>
```

Assume 24 is the Id of your genre and Pop is the name.

Now we will write some javascript code to listen to the click event of this anchor tag. When user clicks on the `a` tag. We will read the href attribute value of the clicked anchor tag and make an ajax request to that using the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

```
$(function(){  // putting our code inside document ready

   $("a.lnkGenre").click(function(e){                 

    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default click event behavior

    var _this=$(this);   
    var songList="";
    $.getJSON(_this.attr("href"),function(data){
        if(data.Status=="Success")
        {
           $.each(data.Items,function(index,item){
              songList="<li>"+item.Title+"</li>";
           });
        }
        $("#songList").html(songList);
    });

 });

});
```

We should have an action method called `Songs` in our `GenreController` which accepts the genre id and returns the list of songs in the Json format now

```
public ActionResult Songs(int id)
{
  List<dynamic> songVMList= new List<dynamic>();
  var songList=repositary.GetSongsForGenre(id);
  foreach(var item in songLsit)
  {
     var sub = new { ID = item.ID, Title= item.Title};
     songVMList.Add(sub); 
  }
  return Json(new { Status = "Success", Items = subCategoryVMList },
                                             JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
}
```